# Second content div fill remaining height where a first content div have variable height

Tags: html, css

I have this html page structure used for different pages:

```
<div class="conteiner">
    <div class="header">green</div>
    <div class="fit_on_content">red<br />red</div>
    <div class="fit_all">aqua</div>
    <div class="footer">yellow</div>
</div>
```

with this css

```
.conteiner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
.header {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
.fit_on_content {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.fit_all {
    background-color: aqua;
    ????
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

`.header` is positioned to the top.
`.footer` is positioned to the bottom.
`.fit_on_content` is positioned under header and has the height of the content that may change from page to page.
`.fit_all` is positioned under fit_on_content and must extend to the footer.

Any idea please?

Thanks

Comment: Check this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/57w9cswv/)

Comment: Going through some older answers of mine and found this. Is there something I can do to make it useful enough to have it at least upvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `display: table`

```css
html,
body { height: 100%; margin: 0 }

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 1px;
}
.page-row-expanded {
    height: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #bbb;
  height: 50px;
}
main {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
main ~ main {
  background-color: #fff;
}
footer {
  background-color: #bbb;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="page-row">
      Header
    </header>
    
    <main class="page-row">
      First content goes here
    </main>
    
    <main class="page-row page-row-expanded">
      Second content goes here
    </main>
    
    <footer class="page-row">
      Copyright, blah blah blah
    </footer>
</div>
```

**Updated** as requested, using `display: flex;`

Note though, you need to add the prefixed properties for browsers that doesn't support flex unprefixed.

```css
html,
body { height: 100%; margin: 0 }

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-row {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.page-row-expanded {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #bbb;
  height: 50px;
}
main {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
main ~ main {
  background-color: #fff;
}
footer {
  background-color: #bbb;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="page-row">
      Header
    </header>
    
    <main class="page-row">
      First content goes here
    </main>
    
    <main class="page-row page-row-expanded">
      Second content goes here
    </main>
    
    <footer class="page-row">
      Copyright, blah blah blah
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the solution flex?

Comment: Another complication, when I modify html code  
 <main class='page-row page-row-extanded'> <iframe src="prova_slave.htm" scrolling="no" style="height:100%;width:100%;" ></iframe> </main>,   
the first solution is ok for chrome and firefox but not for ie11 (window shows scrollbar), the second solution is ok for firefox but not for ie11 (window shows scrollbar) and chrome (iframe height is 0). Any idea please? Thanks

Comment: The first solution does not work for ie11. It seems that the value height = 100% of the <iframe> is calculated on the height of the <body> instead of the height of the <main>.

Comment: If you used `position: absolute` for the iframe in the first solution, then you need to set `position: relative` on the parent (the "main" in this case). ... and in this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/v52qpquo/2/embedded/result/, IE11 works flawless... (if you see a scroll when viewed full page, it is caused by jsfiddle)

Comment: @MAX_1999 When an answer is "the right one for the question", your are supposed to accept that answer, to show future users which answer the questioner preferred.